# Is it possible to create 'sub' containers in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a case where I need to have a 'set of services' that depend on some context. It's not the same as a container scope, because they aren't necessarily nested under 'request' or 'not request'.

More specifically, I'd like to have several services that serve the same function, but for different 'types' in my system.   I could solve this by having a 'registry' service that provides the type->type-specific-service mapping/lookup, This wouldn't even be hard for me to do, but if there was a cleaner/built-into-symfony way to do it, I'd prefer to use that.

Comment: Container scopes aren't limited to a "(non-)request" context.

Comment: No, but scopes are nested, so I would have to either make my 'type-specific' container a subscope of 'request', or make it a subscope of 'container'.  Either way, I couldn't get a type-specific service that worked for both 'request' and 'non-request' scopes.